# Swapping variable in p5.js

Tags: processing, p5.js

I have defined a variable called fighter in my program. I have an if keyPressed function which selects a specific image based on key. The problem I am having is that that images are swapping but overlapping the original image. I also attempted to add an else statement with the fighter in the original position but still same response.

```javascript
var fighter;
var stance;
var kick;
var jab;
var cross;
var mx; //Use to constrain fighter to center of circle
var my;

function preload(){
    stance = loadImage("img/stance.svg");
    kick = loadImage("img/kick.svg");
    jab = loadImage("img/jab.svg");
    cross = loadImage("img/cross.svg");
};

function setup(){
    createCanvas(1280,720);
};



function draw(){
    background(0, 246, 255);
    fill("red");
    ellipse(width/2,height/2,500,500);
    mx = constrain(mouseX,width/2-250,width/2+250);
    my = constrain(mouseY,height/2-250,height/2+250);
    fighter = image(stance,mx,my);


    if(keyIsPressed){
        if((key == "a" || key == "A")){
            fighter = "";
            fighter = image(jab,mx,my);
        }
        else if ((key == "w" || key == "W")) {
            fighter = image(cross,mx,my);
        }
        else if ((key == "s" || key == "S")) {
            fighter = image(kick,mx,my);
        } 
    };

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `fighter` equal to the value returned by the `image()` function for some reason. This doesn't make a ton of sense.

Instead, I think you want to set `fighter` equal to one of the images, and then pass `fighter` into the `image()` function. Something like this:

```
fighter = stance;

if(keyIsPressed){
    if((key == "a" || key == "A")){
        fighter = jab;
    }
    else if ((key == "w" || key == "W")) {
        fighter = cross
    }
    else if ((key == "s" || key == "S")) {
        fighter = kick;
    } 
}

image(fighter, mx,my);
```